# How to update elastic search in batches for multiple id?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a requirement where I need to update a field in elastic search for multiple ids. Currently I am using XcontentBuilder and passing an Id along with field name but it's a for loop that's why time complexity becomes horrible if I pass multiple Ids. Is there a way where I can do same operation in batches?

My Code is like this:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
updateRequest.index("index");
updateRequest.type("_doc");
updateRequest.id("1");
updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
            .field("gender", "male")
        .endObject());
client.update(updateRequest).get();
```

Id is a dynamic field and for each Id I am running a loop using above code.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but you can check If this can be of any help

**Option 1:**

```
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add("1");
    ids.add("2");
    for (String id : ids) {
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
        updateRequest.index("index");
        updateRequest.type("_doc");
        updateRequest.id("1");
        updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder().startObject().field("gender", "male").endObject());
        bulkRequest.add(updateRequest);
    }
    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

**Option 2: Using Script**

```
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add("1");
    ids.add("2");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    String scriptCode = "ctx._source.gender=params.gender";
    params.put("gender", "male");
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    for(String id : ids) {
        UpdateRequestBuilder updateRequestBuilder = client.prepareUpdate("index", "type", id)
                .setScript(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", scriptCode, params));
        bulkRequest.add(updateRequestBuilder);
    }
    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: I have tried all this before that's why i have explicitly mentioned I don't want to do iteration. Please read my question. What if IDs are in 10's ?? For loop isn't the scene here. It has to be in batches.

Comment: this does not fire elasticsearch query for every Id, it prepares the update request and add the requests to bulkRequest. All the requests are executed in bulk.

Comment: My bad. Let me try it...Thanks

Comment: @Pramod how to do this elasticsearch 8?